# Close Button Not Removing Classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

So, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, as I'm not getting any errors in the console, and I commented out my other JQuery/JavaScript code and the issue persists. When I click a thumbnail image, the classes are added just fine, but when I click the close button, the classes don't remove. If I add an alert function on the click of the close button, it works fine.

```js
$('.thumbnail').on('click', function() {

  $(this).find('.modal').addClass('active');
  $(this).find('.modal-image > img').addClass('active');
  $(this).find('.modal-image-caption').addClass('active');

});

$('#close').on('click', function() {

  $(this).parent('.modal').removeClass('active');

  $(this).siblings('.modal-image > img').removeClass('active');
  $(this).siblings('.modal-image-caption').removeClass('active');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="modal">

  <span class="close" id='close'>&times;</span>

  <div class="modal-image">

    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">

  </div>
  <!-- modal-image -->

  <div class="modal-image-caption text-center">

    <p>This is some example text</p>

  </div>
  <!-- modal-image-caption -->

</div>
<!-- modal -->
```

Comment: How many of these modals are there?

Comment: Just one right now. Going to be converting to WordPress so I just need to make sure one works.

Comment: If these are going to repeat, you need to remove the id on the close button, or make it unique, because ids should not be repeated.

Comment: Other than that, are you saying neither of the siblings method work?  Or does `'.modal-image-caption'` work and `'.modal-image > img'` not work?  Because technically the second selector there is not a sibling

Comment: Correct, neither work. I originally just had them selected as $('.modal-img > img') and $('.modal-image-caption'). Also, about the id, I just put that there for S's and G's. I originally just had it as only a class of close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the assumption that `.thumbnail` encloses the modal the click of the `close` button bubbles and triggers the active again.

I added `return false;` to the end of your function.

```js
$('.thumbnail').on('click', function() {

  $(this).find('.modal').addClass('active');
  $(this).find('.modal-image > img').addClass('active');
  $(this).find('.modal-image-caption').addClass('active');

});

$('.close').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent('.modal').removeClass('active');

  $(this).siblings('.modal-image > img').removeClass('active');
  $(this).siblings('.modal-image-caption').removeClass('active');

  return false;
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
HTML:
<div class="thumbnail">
  <div class="modal">

    <span class="close">&times;</span>

    <div class="modal-image">

      <img src="./img/dish.jpg" alt="">

    </div>
    <!-- modal-image -->

    <div class="modal-image-caption text-center">

      <p>This is some example text</p>

    </div>
    <!-- modal-image-caption -->

  </div>
  <!-- modal -->
</div>
```

Comment: Yep that did it. Thanks!

Comment: @valtro05  note that I took the ID of the close button away and changed the close button handler to reference the close class instead.